# Concurrent Statement on a case VHDL

Tags: vhdl

Hi all i'm trying to synthesize a VHDL code using alliance tool. But im having an illegal concurrent statement error. I'm new in VHDL and i'm trying to understand the concurrent and sequential statements, So i dont really understand why i'm getting a illegal concurrent statement inside a the case. Could you please help me on this error.

Here is a piece of the code, but is basically the same:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity reg_P is
port (
   A : in unsigned(7 downto 0);
   CLK : in std_logic;
   EstPresente : in unsigned(7 downto 0);
   P : out unsigned(7 downto 0);
   RI : in unsigned(7 downto 0);
   RPS : in std_logic
);
end reg_P;
architecture FromVerilog of reg_P is
 signal P_Reg : unsigned(7 downto 0);
 begin
 P <= P_Reg;
 process (CLK)
  begin
   if (rising_edge(CLK)) then
     if ((not RPS) = '1') then
       P_Reg <= X"00";
     else
      case EstPresente is
       when X"02" then
        case RI is
          when X"16" then
            P_Reg <= A;
          when X"36" then
            P_Reg <= (P_Reg - X"01");
          when X"26" then
            P_Reg <= (P_Reg - X"01");
          when others then
            P_Reg <= P_Reg;
        end case;
        when others then
        P_Reg <= P_Reg;
      end case;
    end if;
  end if;
 end process;
end architecture;
```

Answer (score 3):

The `then`s in your case statement choices should be the compound delimiter `=>`.

Replace those 6 instances and your code analyzes.

```
      case EstePresente is
       when X"02" =>
        case RI is
          when X"16" =>
            P_Reg <= A;
          when X"36" =>
            P_Reg <= (P_Reg - X"01");
          when X"26" =>
            P_Reg <= (P_Reg - X"01");
          when others =>
            P_Reg <= P_Reg;
        end case;
        when others =>
        P_Reg <= P_Reg;
      end case;
```

> ghdl -a reg_p.vhdl
>   reg_p.vhdl:26:19: '=>' is expected instead of 'then'
>   ghdl: compilation error

From a historical perspective synthesis was so costly you were expected to validate your models through simulation before synthesis.

Simulation tools tend to have better error reporting.